# ASP.NET MVC 5 : foreach loop sort and write output in specific order

Tags: c#, list, sorting, foreach, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a foreach loop in my view and I need it to write data in specific order id HTML sections. The problem is that i don't want HTML section to be seen if there is no data for that section.

```
int idSection1 = 1;
int idSection2 = 2;
int idSection3 = 3;

@foreach (var item in Model.ItemList)
{
    if (itme.IdSection == idSection1)
    {
        <div>
            <h4>Section 1</h4>
            foreach (var data in Model.ItemList)
            {
                if (data.IdSection == 1)
                {
                    <p>data</p>
                }
                idSection1 = idSection1 + 10;
            }
        </div>
    }

    if (itme.IdSection == idSection2)
    {
        <div>
            <h4>Section 2</h4>
            foreach (var data in Model.ItemList)
            {
                if (data.IdSection == 2)
                {
                    <p>data</p>
                }
                idSection2 = idSection1 + 10;
            }
        </div>
    }

    if (itme.IdSection == idSection3)
    {
        <div>
            <h4>Section 3</h4>
            foreach (var data in Model.ItemList)
            {
                if (data.IdSection == 2)
                {
                    <p>data</p>
                }
                idSection3 = idSection3 + 10;
            }
        </div>
    }
}
```

And with this my output, depending on my list and in what order data was entered is this:

```
<h4>Section 2</h4>
    <p>data 1</p>
    <p>data 2</p>
    <p>data 3</p>
    
<h4>Section 1</h4>
    <p>data 1</p>
    
<h4>Section 3</h4>
    <p>data 1</p>
    <p>data 2</p>
```

And I need it to be this, with important part that for example "Section 2" doesn't need to written if there is no data for it! :

```
 <h4>Section 1</h4>
    <p>data 1</p>
    
<h4>Section 2</h4>
    <p>data 1</p>
    <p>data 2</p>
    <p>data 3</p>   
    
<h4>Section 3</h4>
    <p>data 1</p>
    <p>data 2</p>
```

Comment: sort your data first before looping

Comment: Rethink your code, outer loop and inner foreach both are iterating `Model.ItemList` - waste of time. You should sort your ItemList by `Section` using Linq, and then only render it. Single for each iteration is sufficient when you detect the change in data.IdSection, end the previous list and start new one.

Comment: Yes I was thinking of doing that. Other idea is that I code the sections needed and make them not visible. Have only one loop and if loop writes data in specific section then that section becomes visible.

Comment: Your code shows `<p>data</p>`. Where does the number in your output come from? Your code also shows a bunch of copy/paste typos: `itme`, and `idSection2 = idSection1 + 10` for example

Comment: About that `+10` part, does it mean you're grouping in "Section 1" every item which `IdSection` ends with 1? (1, 11, 21, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can refactor your `foreach` loop to just this:

```
var idSection=1;

@foreach (var item in Model.ItemList.OrderBy(x=>x.IdSection))
{
    if(Model.ItemList.Any())
    {
        <div>
            <h4>Section @item.IdSection</h4>
            foreach (var data in Model.ItemList.OrderBy(x=>x.IdSection))
            {
                <p>data @data.IdSection</p>
                idSection = idSection + 10;
            }
        </div>  
    }
}
```

This will sort your list based on the section id and it will also check if there are any elements in the list.

Comment: I don't really get why you'd check `if(Model.ItemList.Any())` *inside* a `foreach`. It's not like this would change between two iterations. Besides, this code will write every item in each and every section. Not really sure it's what is needed here